# Find all functions $f(x^2-y^2)=f(xy)(f(x)+f(y))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that, for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$f(x^2-y^2)=f(xy)(f(x)+f(y)).$$

Both $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1/2$ are solutions.

Swapping $x,y$ in the equation implies that $f$ is even. Plugging in $x=y=0$ implies that $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1/2$.

If $f(0)=0$, then plugging in $y=0$ implies that $f(x^2)=0$. So $f(t)=0$ for $t\geq0$, and $f$ even means that $f=0$ is the only solution in this case.

I'm struggling though with the case $f(0)=1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Plugging in $y=0$ gives $f(x^2)=f(0)(f(x)+f(0))$, which, after plugging in $f(0)=\frac 1 2$, gives $$f(x^2)=\frac 1 2 f(x) + \frac 1 4$$
on the other hand, plugging in $x=y$ gives $f(0)=f(x^2)(f(x)+f(x))$, which is $$\frac 1 2=2f(x)f(x^2)$$
Eliminating $f(x^2)$ in those two equations provides $$2(f(x))^2+f(x)-1=0$$
which implies either $f(x)=\frac 1 2$ or $f(x)=-1$. Since $f(0)=\frac 1 2$, we can safely conclude that $f=\frac 1 2$ is the solution.

Comment: I believe there is still some more work to do. You have shown that for a specific $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $f(x)=1/2$ or $f(x)=-1$. But although $f(0)=1/2$, there is nothing stopping e.g. $f(42)=-1$. But thank you for the progress!

Comment: @dancm The answer shows that $f(x) \in \{1/2,-1\}$ for all $x$. Now assume that some $f(x_0) = -1$. Then $1/2 = -2f(x_0^2)$, i.e. $f(x_0^2) = -1/4$ which is impossible.